# How to print not null values on php

Tags: php

I am so new to PHP, now i am trying to print the not null values. I have following php code which throws me all values including null and not nulls. In my website I need only not null values.

```
        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $stock['stsymbol']?><td>
           <td><?php echo $stock['noshares']?><td>
            <td><?php echo $stock['purchaseprice']?><td>
             <td><?php echo $stock['datepurchased']?><td>
              <td><?php echo $stock['Original Value']?><td>

             <td><?php echo $stock['Current Price']?><td>
             <td><?php echo $stock['Current Value']?><td>
        </tr>


    <?php } // end foreach ?>
```

Comment: `empty($stock['Current Price']) ? "" : echo $stock['Current Price'];`

Comment: why don't you use `is_null()` to test null values

Answer (score 2):

change the all td like this example :

```
<?php if(!is_null($stock['stsymbol'])){ ?>
    <td><?php echo $stock['stsymbol']; ?><td>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try using this

<td><?php if(!empty($stock['stsymbol'])){ echo $stock['stsymbol']; }?><td>
```

Comment: tried, but it displays no values, even the values are gone

Answer (score 0):

The basic pattern you want to follow to conditionally print a value is

```
  <?php 
      if (!empty($stock['stsymbol'])) {
             echo $stock['stsymbol'];
      }
  ?>
```

This can be shortened by using a ternary if

```
  <?php echo (!empty($stock["stsymbol"]))?$stock["stsymbol"]:"" ?>
```

**UPDATE**

Much discussion has gone on in the comments regarding the mechanism used to test for a null value. I thought it might be good to recap the merits of each.

> **is_null** - returns true if the variable is strictly null or undefined (will issue a notice if it is undefined)
>
> **empty** - returns true if the variable is falsy or undefined (will not issue a notice)
>
> **!$val** - same as empty but with a notice with undefined values.

Comment: not me but i think empty can catch $string = ""

Comment: Not me either, but you should not use `empty` unless you can't guarantee that the variable/index will exist. If you expect the variable/index to exist, just compare it to `false`.

Comment: There is some downvoters who doesn't leave comments, i know it bothered me too

Comment: @deceze is the comparison with false a performance thing or a way to trigger a notice to test your assumptions?

Comment: @Orange `empty` suppresses error messages. Don't suppress errors unless you have a legitimate case to do so. That's all.

Comment: not me as well, and I tried this but it does not work as well

Answer (score 0):

php has [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) clearly for situation like this. use

```
if (!is_null($varname)) echo $varname;
```

Comment: if this is a database result it's going to annoyingly be a empty string instead of null

Comment: @Orange That entirely depends on the database and database interface.

Comment: @deceze I know it was true with old mysql_* function ... are null's returned as nulls in mysqli & pdo (I assume with pdo it can be driver dependant)?

Comment: @Orange I can't remember off the top of my head, recently I'm into Postgres + PDO. I'm not sure there off the top of my head either though. ;P

Comment: Okay to revise my previous statement... if this a a database result it may be an empty string instead of a null based on a series of obscure conditions that no one can remember.... your better off using !empty if you don't care about the difference between a null and an empty string.

Comment: @Orange In that case you should use `!= false` or simply `if ($var)`, not `empty`! [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid the problem altogether and use *another foreach* loop in your current foreach.

It goes like this:

```
foreach ($stock as $key=>$value) {
    echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
```